# Replace array of signs inside a span

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to wrap each sign in the given array inside a span tag to be able to render it to DOM:

Here is the signs array:

```
const signs = ['!!', '?!', '!?', '...', '..', '.', '?', '!', ':', '؟!', '!؟', '؟'];
```

I can replace each sign individually like this:

```
result = result.replace(/([\:])/g, "<span class='some-class'>&nbsp;:</span>");
```

The above code put : sign inside a span.

How can I do this for all of array signs without hard  coding them?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```js
let result = "!! ?! !? ... .. . ? ! : ؟!, !؟ ؟";
const signs = ['!!', '?!', '!?', '...', '..', '.', '?', '!', ':', '؟!', '!؟', '؟']; 
signs.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
const regex = new RegExp(signs.map(x => 
    x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join('|'),
    'g');
result = result.replace(regex, "<span class='some-class'>&nbsp;$&</span>");
console.log(result)
```

Here,

- `signs.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)` sorts the `signs` array items by length in descending order
- `signs.map(x => x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'))` - escapes all the special chars in the items to make them match literal chars inside a regex
- `....join('|')` - creates an alternation regex
- `new RegExp(..., 'g')` - defines a RegExp object that matches all pattern occurrences in the string
- `$&` in the replacement pattern inserts the match value.

Answer (score -1):

You could use:

```
result = signs.map(sign => "<span class='some-class'>&nbsp;" + sign + "</span>");
```

or if you want to use regex it would be overcomplicated:

```
result = signs.map(sign => sign.replace(/(.+)/g, "<span class='some-class'>&nbsp;$1</span>"));
```

Comment: `/(.+)/g` will match all the string from beginning to end, OP is wrapping the signs in the `sign` array only.